Kafkajs consumer invalid message
We have written kafka consumer in node.js and using "kafkajs" library for it.
Also we are using "@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry" for schema registry.
After receiving the event if I convert message from Buffer to string, getting special character at the start of message.
��
{
    "Id": "123",
    "Description": "abc",
    "ProductHierarchyId": "124",
    "AbbreviatedDescription": "abc",
    "KeycodeType": "yyy",
    "PriceTier": "1UP",
    "ExternalReferences": [
        {
            "ReferenceType": "refId",
            "Value": "12344"
        }
    ],
    "Attributes": []
}

Used "toString()" method to convert from buffer to string. Schema we are using is JSON schema.
Also if I try to decode message using schema registry, it is giving  "ConfluentSchemaRegistryValidationError: invalid payload\n    at JsonSchema.validatePayload error.
Need help in resolving this.
